# How to convert 1D numpy array of tuples to 2D numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `numpy` array of `tuples`:

```
import numpy as np
the_tuples = np.array([(1, 4), (7, 8)], dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

I would like to have a 2D `numpy` array instead:

```
the_2Darray = np.array([[1,4],[7,8]])
```

I have tried doing several things, such as

```
import numpy as np
the_tuples = np.array([(1, 4), (7, 8)], dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
the_2Darray = np.array([*the_tuples])
```

How can I convert it?

Comment: `np.array([list(item) for item in the_tuples])`

Comment: This is a `structured array`, not an array of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to add `the_tuples.astype(object)`.

```
import numpy as np
the_tuples = np.array([(1, 4), (7, 8)], dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
the_tuples = the_tuples.astype(object)
the_2Darray = np.array([*the_tuples])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a `structured array` - 1d with a `compound dtype`:

```
In [2]: arr = np.array([(1, 4), (7, 8)], dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])

In [3]: arr.shape, arr.dtype
Out[3]: ((2,), dtype([('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')]))
```

`recfunctions` has a function designed to do such a conversion:

```
In [4]: import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rf

In [5]: arr1 = rf.structured_to_unstructured(arr)    
In [6]: arr1
Out[6]: 
array([[1, 4],
       [7, 8]])
```

`view` works if all fields have the same dtype, but the shape isn't kept well:

```
In [7]: arr.view('int')
Out[7]: array([1, 4, 7, 8])
```

The `tolist` produces a list of tuples (instead of a list of lists):

```
In [9]: arr.tolist()
Out[9]: [(1, 4), (7, 8)]
```

Which can be used as the basis for making a new array:

```
In [10]: np.array(arr.tolist())
Out[10]: 
array([[1, 4],
       [7, 8]])
```

Note that when you created the array (in [2]) you had to use the list of tuples format.